# Cannot find my data in lost+found folder in home folder

Tags: home-directory

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I kept all my data in lost+found folder in home folder. If I open this folder, it is coming that I do not have permission to open this folder. Here are the commands I am getting:

```
srujana@srujana-desktop:/home$ ls -l /home
total 20
drwx------  2 srujana srujana 16384 Jul 22 00:40 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 32 srujana srujana  4096 Sep 28 17:43 srujana
```

I don't understand where has all my data gone.
Please help me.Thank you.

Comment: please reply yaar....its very urgent....please please respond me....

Comment: Did you store in lost+found in the /home folder or your home folder? Note the difference.

Comment: Thanks for responding Jobin....I had stored in lost+found in /home folder only...please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You probably stored files in `lost+found` using super user privileges and would required them to retrieve files from this folder. The purpose of this folder can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix).

To retrive files, do the following in a terminal:

```
sudo chmod 775 /home/lost+found
mkdir /home/$USER/recovered_files
cp /home/lost+found/* /home/$USER/recovered_files
rm /home/lost+found
mklost+found
```

Your files should be present in recovered_files in your home directory.

The last command recreates the `lost+found` folder(This is the recommended way of creating a `lost+found` folder(if not present).

Comment: srujana@srujana-desktop:~$ sudo chmod 775 /home/lost+found
srujana@srujana-desktop:~$ mkdir /home/$USER/recovered_files
mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/srujana/recovered_files': File exists
srujana@srujana-desktop:~$ cp /home/lost+found/* /home/$USER/recovered_files
cp: cannot stat `/home/lost+found/*': No such file or directory
srujana@srujana-desktop:~$ rm /home/lost+found
rm: cannot remove `/home/lost+found': Is a directory
srujana@srujana-desktop:~$ mklost+found
mklost+found 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
mkdir: File exists

Comment: Thanks Jobin for ur reply...This is what I am getting...And if I open that lost+found folder nothing is present and is empty...Please help me...

Comment: This means there are no files in `lost+found`. Not sure why.

Comment: But I kept so much of GB in it after installing ubuntu in my desktop 2 months back....Is that all gone?or any virus had eaten it away?

Comment: Do you have a separate /home partition?  Maybe it is not mounted/unmounted the same way when you saved your files, so they are either being concealed by the mounted /home or not mounted at all.